# Есть ли в сети ресурсы на которых можно отдать свою поделку на поругание?

Tags: android, java

Всем привет.
Такой вот вопросик возник...
Допустим прога написана (у меня разработка в завершающей стадии сейчас). Сам потестирую-поковыряю - дело ясное. Но! Таки хотелось бы чтобы кто-то ещё попользовался, посмотрел, что к чему, мож отыскал бы багов каких, дал бы рекомендаций...
Есть такие ресурсы в сети, есть энтузиасты, к которым можно обратиться? :)
Сразу скажу, шо денег на проге зарабатывать не собираюсь. Делал её в рамках расширения кругозора, отдавать желающим буду бесплатно. Ну мож, если оправдает надежды по работоспособности, выложу на гуглоплей - тоже за бесплатно... Хотя за это гринов отдать надо... 25 что ли...
Но перед выкладыванием на серьезные ресурсы желательно бы серьезно и потестить...
Кто что посоветует?

Comment: 4pda. А без гугл плея не знаю кто будет морочится с установкой apk. И как его не подписанный поставить на устройство?

Comment: не понял, а в чем проблема с установкой? я ставлю свои апк на любой девайс. просто галочку устанавливаю - разрешить установку из неизвестных источников и всё вроде :)

А лезть сразу на гуглплей, так там за любую мелочевку (типа иконка не понравилась), начинают какашками кидаться :) Хоть и бесплатные приложения юзают.

Comment: @Demon051 - можно запустить приложение в альфа или бета версии, прикрепить к версии группу в гугл+ и приложение будет доступно только участникам группы, не более.

[Альфа и бета тестирование android приложений][1]

[1]: http://habrahabr.ru/post/189912/

Comment: @ua6xh в любом случае надо искать тех, кто в эту группу вступит)

Comment: вот именно, Suvitruf :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если бы это была игра, я бы порекомендовал 4PDA. Мы там постоянно в подфоруме по разработке делимся своими наработками.

Думаю, если вы там приложение своё покажете, то камнями не закидают )

**upd:**

[вот по софту раздел](http://4pda.ru/forum/index.php?showforum=549)

[вот по играм раздел](http://4pda.ru/forum/index.php?showforum=550)

или иностранный [xda-developers](http://forum.xda-developers.com/android/apps-games)

Comment: Не, это не игра. Попробую показать :)

Comment: @Demon051 обновил ответ, ссылки добавил)

Comment: @Demon051 да не за что. Из иностранных бы ещё порекомендовал бы ещё http://forum.xda-developers.com/android/apps-games

Answer (score 0):

При подачи приложения в samsung apps они тщательно тестируют его перед публикованием и отправляют вам список багов